# Difference between spi_driver.id_table and spi_driver.driver.of_match_table

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I'm currently trying to understand how Linux drivers work. As far as I know, A driver's probe/init function is called when the kernel parses the corresponding `.compatible` string in the device tree. However, in the arizona-spi driver it looks like there are multiple compatible strings referenced in different members:

```c
static const struct spi_device_id arizona_spi_ids[] = {
  { "wm5102", WM5102 },
  { "wm5110", WM5110 },
  { },
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(spi, arizona_spi_ids);

static struct spi_driver arizona_spi_driver = {
  .driver = {
    .name   = "arizona",
    .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
    .pm = &arizona_pm_ops,

    // Contains e.g. "wlf,wm5102"
    .of_match_table = of_match_ptr(arizona_of_match),

  },
  .probe    = arizona_spi_probe,
  .remove   = arizona_spi_remove,
  .id_table = arizona_spi_ids,      // Contains "wm5102" and "wm5110"
};
```

This is an excerpt from [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/mfd/arizona-spi.c?id=refs/tags/v3.12.31).

So what is the difference between `arizona_spi_driver.id_table` and `arizona_spi_driver.driver.of_match_table`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several mechanism for driver matching. The id_table is intended to be used for finding a match from stripped device-tree entries (without vendor part), while of_match_table is used to find a match from full device-tree entries (the ones with vendor part).

If you check, arizona_of_match is defined as this:

```
const struct of_device_id arizona_of_match[] = {
    { .compatible = "wlf,wm5102", .data = (void *)WM5102 },
    { .compatible = "wlf,wm5110", .data = (void *)WM5110 },
    { .compatible = "wlf,wm8280", .data = (void *)WM8280 },
    { .compatible = "wlf,wm8997", .data = (void *)WM8997 },
    {},
};
```

**wlf** is the vendor part for this case, while arizona_spi_ids doesn't contain the vendor part.

Hence, if you have something like this in your device tree:

> compatible = "myvendor,wm5102"

Your device **will match against id_table** but **not against of_match_table** since the vendor is different.

The kernel will do matching against of_match_table first before check id_table (see **spi_get_device_id** in [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/spi/spi.c?id=refs/tags/v3.12.31)). The device matching priority is: of_match_table > acpi_driver > id_table.