# without id_table, of_match_table can't match device tree node.And with id_table, of_match_table can. Why?

Tags: linux-device-driver, device-tree

I have a problem when I use `of_match_table` to match device tree node.

Device tree node information (laser-radio) like this

```dts
{
    i2c@7000c000 {
        laser-radio@29 {
        compatible = "lyz,vl53l0x";
        reg = <0x29>;
        };
    };
};
```

and when I just use `of_match_table()`

```c
static const struct of_device_id vl53l0x_dt_match[] = {
    { .compatible = "lyz,vl53l0x" },
    { }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, vl53l0x_dt_match);

struct i2c_driver vl53l0x_driver = {
    .driver =
        {
            .name = "vl53l0x",
            .owner = THIS_MODULE,
            .of_match_table = vl53l0x_dt_match,
        },
    .probe = vl53l0x_probe,
    .remove = vl53l0x_remove,
};
```

This doesn't work. but if I use `id_table`

```c
static const struct i2c_device_id vl53l0x_id[] = {
    { "vl53l0x", 0 },
    {}
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(i2c, vl53l0x_id);

static const struct of_device_id vl53l0x_dt_match[] = {
    { .compatible = "lyz,vl53l0x" },
    { }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, vl53l0x_dt_match);

struct i2c_driver vl53l0x_driver = {
    .driver =
        {
            .name = "vl53l0x",
            .owner = THIS_MODULE,
            .of_match_table = vl53l0x_dt_match,
        },
    .probe = vl53l0x_probe,
    .remove = vl53l0x_remove,
    .id_table = vl53l0x_id,
};
```

It works. I don't know why, and when I print compatible it also show `lyz,vl53l0x`.

How to use `of_match_table` to match a node? Did I do something wrong?

(linux 4.9)

I also conducted some interesting experiments and found that the node was indeed matched. It's just that when I commented out the '.id_table', even though the match occurred, it wouldn't enter the probe function. However, with only the '.id_table', it can enter the probe function after matching.

experiment steps:

1. add some `printk` into `i2c_device_match`
2. insmod

```c
static int i2c_device_match(struct device *dev, struct device_driver *drv) {
  struct i2c_client *client = i2c_verify_client(dev);
  struct i2c_driver *driver;
    printk("lyz : i2c_device_match\n");
  if (!client){
    return 0;
    }
    printk("%s:  drv->of_match_table->compatible= %s\n", __func__, drv->of_match_table->compatible);
  /* Attempt an OF style match */
  if (of_driver_match_device(dev, drv)){
        printk("lyz : get right match\n");
        return 1;
    }

  ...
  return 0;
}
```

If with `.id_table`
[with id_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3RRa.png)

If without `.id_table`
[without id_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdJV1.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between spi\_driver.id\_table and spi\_driver.driver.of\_match\_table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583954/difference-between-spi-driver-id-table-and-spi-driver-driver-of-match-table)

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be caused by the difference between 'id_table' and 'of_match_table'.Because if I use the wrong ‘id_table' but the correct 'of_match_table', it can still match against the correct node.

Comment: Ah, now I see. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9.337/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core.c#L1034. Here is your problem. Compare to https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.8/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core-base.c#L675 in recent kernel.